# google is not define even after adding the client library

Tags: next.js, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

i'm trying to use google sign in in my nextjs application.
I added the script given on the googel website the client library.This library

and another script to initialize a google sign in instance.
here is my code

```
const handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
  console.log(response)
}

export default function App(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  const check = router.pathname === '/watch';

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Head>
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
        <script>
          window.onload = function () {
            google.accounts.id.initialize({
              client_id: '842216765313-pk5v3gjog9nt2q4uaq7okbp8okjubfnh.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              callback: handleCredentialResponse
            })
          };
        </script>
      </Head>
      {/* '' */}
      <MainContextProvider>
        <Box sx={{ height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <Navbar />
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={3} sx={{ marginTop: '8px' }}>
            {!check && <Drawer />}
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Stack>
        </Box>
      </MainContextProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Error:
it saying google is not defined.